# How to obtain the following marginal distribution

Tags: probability, marginal-distribution, integral

I'm struggling on how to calculate the marginal $f(x)$. I'm trying to integrate $f(x,y)$ by $y$, but I couldn't solve it. The pdf is the following.

$\displaystyle f(x) =  \int_0^{\infty} f(x,y)\text{d}y =  \cfrac{e^{-(y+x/y)}}{y}\text{d}y$, where $y,x>0$.

I've been triyng to use integration by parts and substitution for a long time now, but I couldn't solve it. It is an exercise in Sheldon Ross book.

Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Hi. Please add the [tag:self-study] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral does not have a closed-form solution, so there is no simplification beyond stating the integral in its present form.  If you really want to, you can use the substitution $r=1/y$ to get the equivalent form:

$$f(x) 
= \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{y} \cdot \exp \Big( - y - \frac{x}{y} \Big) \ dy
= \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{r} \cdot \exp \Big( - \frac{1}{r} - xr \Big) \ dr.$$

In either case, you will need to compute this integral numerically.  There are many ways you could do this, but one way would be to find some appropriate upper and lower bounds for the integrand (which have integrals that exist in closed form) and use these to "sandwich" the integrand.  This would allow you to squeeze the integral between an upper and lower bound composed of finite sums of computable terms, plus a computable remainder term.

Let's try to construct a numerical evaluation method in this way.  Start by observing that for all $0 < y_L \leqslant y \leqslant y_U$ we have the bounds:

$$\frac{1}{y_U} \cdot \exp \Big( - y - \frac{x}{y_L} \Big) \leqslant \frac{1}{y} \cdot \exp \Big( - y - \frac{x}{y} \Big)
\leqslant \frac{1}{y_L} \cdot \exp \Big( - y - \frac{x}{y_U} \Big).$$

Consequently, for any increasing set of values $0=y_0 < y_1 < y_2 < y_3 < \cdots < y_N < \infty$ we have the computable integral bounds:

$$\begin{align}
f(x) 
&= \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{y} \cdot \exp \Big( - y - \frac{x}{y} \Big) \ dy \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \int \limits_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} \frac{1}{y} \cdot \exp \Big( - y - \frac{x}{y} \Big) \ dy + \int \limits_{y_N}^\infty \frac{1}{y} \cdot \exp \Big( - y - \frac{x}{y} \Big) \ dy \\[6pt]
&\geqslant \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \int \limits_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} \frac{1}{y_{n+1}} \cdot \exp \Big( - y - \frac{x}{y_{n}} \Big) \ dy \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{y_{n+1}} \cdot \exp \Big( - \frac{x}{y_{n}} \Big) \int \limits_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} \exp(-y) \ dy \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{\exp (-y_n) - \exp (-y_{n+1})}{y_{n+1}} \cdot \exp \Big( - \frac{x}{y_{n}} \Big), \\[12pt]
f(x) 
&= \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{y} \cdot \exp \Big( - y - \frac{x}{y} \Big) \ dy \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \int \limits_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} \frac{1}{y} \cdot \exp \Big( - y - \frac{x}{y} \Big) \ dy + \int \limits_{y_N}^\infty \frac{1}{y} \cdot \exp \Big( - y - \frac{x}{y} \Big) \ dy \\[6pt]
&\leqslant \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \int \limits_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} \frac{1}{y_n} \cdot \exp \Big( - y - \frac{x}{y_{n+1}} \Big) \ dy + \int \limits_{y_N}^\infty \frac{1}{y_N} \cdot \exp (-y) \ dy \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{y_n} \cdot \exp \Big( - \frac{x}{y_{n+1}} \Big) \int \limits_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}} \exp(-y) \ dy + \frac{1}{y_N} \int \limits_{y_N}^\infty \exp (-y) \ dy \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{\exp (-y_n) - \exp (-y_{n+1})}{y_n} \cdot \exp \Big( - \frac{x}{y_{n+1}} \Big) + \frac{\exp (-y_N)}{y_N}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

We can choose a set of values $0=y_0 < y_1 < y_2 < y_3 < \cdots < y_N < \infty$ that are sufficiently close together, with $y_N$ sufficiently large to bring the upper and lower bounds close together and thereby "squeeze" the true value of $f(x)$ between arbitrarily close bounds.  This method should allow you to compute the function up to arbitrary accuracy.

Comment: +1 I stared at the integral and came to the same conclusion. I guess we could replace $f(x)$ for some other function depending on what we're trying to do, but it wouldn't be equal to this integral. Like taking a function $h > f$  $\forall\ x$ might be handy in some analysis problems.

Answer (score 0):

One can obtain a form for the marginal density that is relatively convenient to evaluate numerically in many software packages (even Excel!).  Using *Mathematica* one finds the following:

```
jointPDF = Exp[-y - x/y]/y;
pdfx = Integrate[jointPDF, {y, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> x > 0]
(* 2 BesselK[0, 2 Sqrt[x]] *)
```

$$f(x)=2 K_0\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)$$

Using a Bessel K function already programmed is (almost always) more stable than growing your own.  A partial plot of the pdf in R might look like the following:

```
x <- c(2:40)/10
plot(x, 2*besselK(2*sqrt(x), 0), type="l", ylab="Probability density",
  cex.lab=1.5, font.lab=2, xlim=c(0, 4), lwd=3, las=1, axes=FALSE)
axis(1, c(0:4), pos=0)
axis(2, las=1, pos=0)
```

[image: Plot of pdf]

Also the marginal pdf of $Y$ is found with the following:

```
pdfy = Integrate[jointPDF, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> y > 0]
(* E^-y *)
```

$$g(y)=e^{-y}$$